# Proving homology class of a loop to be zero

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Consider the curves $ \gamma_i$ and $ \delta$ on the  surface of genus $2$ as pictured with orientations on $\gamma_i$. Show that $ \delta=0$ and $ \gamma_1=\gamma_2\ + \gamma_3\ $ in $H_1$.

The part $\delta= 0$ can be proved using the following fact : $\delta$ can be regarded as a map $f:\Bbb S^1 \rightarrow X $ and then $f$ can be extended to $\tilde f:W \rightarrow X $ where $W$ is an orientable surface with boundary $\Bbb S^1 $.

Need help for proving other part.[image]

[image]

Comment: Just apply your fact to $\gamma_2+\gamma_3-\gamma_1$.

Comment: If I cut two holed torus vertically then $\gamma_2\ - \gamma_1\ + \gamma_3$  will be the boundary of a part of this surface and this part is orientable, am I right.

Comment: Suggesting that you cut the two holed torus "vertically" does not sound correct. Instead, cut the two holed torus along $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 \cup \gamma_3$.

Comment: If I cut the two holed torus along $ \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 \cup \gamma_3$ then parts of this surface is orientable with orientable boundary given by - traverse $\gamma_1\  and\ \gamma_3$ according to the direction given in the picture and traverse $\gamma_2$ with the direction opposite to the direction given in the picture for $\gamma_2$. Am I right now.

Comment: I have also attached the picture of cutted part of this two holed torus with my question as my attempt. It will helpful to me if you comment on this.

Comment: Yes, that looks right now.